# How to make webpage compatible with all resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I've completely designed my webpage out, but I've noticed that if I drop the resolution down, things don't look the way they should.  Is there a way to make my webpage work in all resolutions without completely starting from scratch again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to preserve layout at a cost to user-experience, you can set min-width and min-height on the body element itself.  (The min-height attribute may not be respected, but with min-width set, height should come out the same, anyway, since everything inside will render the same.)  This would cause scrolling for lower resolutions, but elements in the page should have positioning as you'd prefer for higher resolutions.

If full redesign is an actual option, you may wish to create a Mobile site, then detect if the client has to scroll (checking window height and width), you can have some link suggesting they use the mobile site.  That solution would have the added benefit of having the mobile site in place, in case visiting via phone/tablet is commonly occurring.  Downside is that now you would have two sites to maintain.